# Are there baby drinks closer to breast-milk?

Tags: neuroscience, antibody

Many women cannot or will not feed their children with breast-milk. It is my understanding breast-milk has many advantages over formula. Some psychological like oxytocin and some physiological like advanced antibodies. Have there been any attempts to create a formula with better psychological and physiological properties? Is it even possible to include antibodies in formula or milk?

Comment: How can artificial milk induce psychological response ?

Comment: @biogirllajja adding oxytocin or something simular

Comment: The psychological effect is two-way - Both Mother and Child are involved. Any formula would affect only child.

Answer (score 3):

It is definitely possible to include antibodies and other biological molecules in formula to better approximate that of its mother's milk.  **However**, there's no way you could mass-produce this. Every mother has unique antibodies, even horomones that are the same in different people are present at different concentrations. The current "formula" on the market is good for as many people as possible.

Isolating antibodies from a mother to include in formula milk would be insanely, *insanely* expensive. Think thousands of dollars for a carton of formula. Not to mention the hassle of frequent blood and serum draws from the mother for antibody isolation.

So, yes, this is possible (and I wouldn't be surprised if someone with a lot of money to burn has tried it). It's not remotely cost-effective or feasible, though.